# How to solve Error: Maximum update depth exceeded?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I started learning React Native 2 weeks ago and I got at the installing plugins chapter. I installed **react-native-popover-view** and I don't know but for me I get the error:

`Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

I searched around and after staying 2 days on this I understood that I have setState in render(), because I have the Modal in App render(). I tried to figure out how to change it, but without success.

So I have the Modal.js class:

```
class Modal extends Component {
  state = {
    isVisible: true
  }

  closePopover() {
    this.setState({ isVisible: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <Popover
          isVisible={this.state.isVisible}
          fromView={this.touchable}
          onRequestClose={() => this.closePopover()}>
          <View style={styles.closeXContainer}>
              <Image source={closeX} style={styles.closeX} onPress={this.closePopover()} />
            </View>
          <Text>I'm the content of this popover!</Text>
        </Popover>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and in the App.js, when the page loads, the modal should start first, covering the App.js component, that could be seen on the back.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Modal />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Someone can please help with this? How the code should be to not get that error anymore?

Comment: change `onPress={this.closePopover()}` to `onPress={() => this.closePopover()}`

Comment: thank you very much Nicolas!!! it works.

Comment: TO avoid to create a new function on each call, you should just do it like this: onPress={this.closePopover}, without the (), so that the function is not executed on render. If you pass no paramters, just pass the function without the brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is due to when you call `onPress={this.closePopover()}` on Image , it calls the function and causes the app to re-render which again causes function to be invoked, and hence an infinite loop. The best way would be calling it directly without parentheses `onPress={this.closePopover}` or create an anonymous function `onPress={() => this.closePopover()}`, which gets executed only once

Answer (score 1):

your problem is in the call of the function `this.closePopover()` in order to fix it, you only need to change it to:

```
class Modal extends Component {
  state = {
    isVisible: true
  }

  closePopover() {
    this.setState({ isVisible: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <Popover
          isVisible={this.state.isVisible}
          fromView={this.touchable}
          onRequestClose={this.closePopover}>
          <View style={styles.closeXContainer}>
              <Image source={closeX} style={styles.closeX} onPress={this.closePopover} />
            </View>
          <Text>I'm the content of this popover!</Text>
        </Popover>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this help.